# Remote MYSQL Database Access

Tags: java, mysql

I have developed an application in java that access remote mysql database. While I am running it by netbeans IDE of system which have running that wamp server. But while i try I make connection in another system to remote system database by netbeans it shows following error.

Unable to add connection, Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.14:3306/test using(CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.

Please, kindly help me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

From [mysql forums](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,53090,73282#msg-73282)

> You could be getting this because (1) the URL of the DB is wrong, because (2) the DB isn't set up to accept connections from the web host, or because (3) some intermediate networking component is misconfigured. (1) is your problem; (2) and (3) might be your problem or the web hosting's problem, depending on where the DB is located, what administrative privileges on the DB that you have, and how the networking is set up.

You need to have the right privileges to be able to connect to MySQL remotely. There are several tools available to set it up.

[Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html) is an article outlining several steps of which the grant step is most commonly needed.

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON foo.* TO bar@'202.54.10.20' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

There has also been problems reported when connecting to MySQL databases in Windows Vista, but i'm not sure wether this is relevant to this case or not.

Comment: Your solution worked fine some system of LAN. So thank you very much.But now i solved above problem with clear way.I stopped firewall now it works fine. Can you help me how to edit firewall setting to acceppt/reject incoming and outgoing connection vai TCP/IP.....

Comment: I'm afraid i don't know much about firewalls.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have ssh access to the server? I would have run a tunnel with ssh, plink or putty (ssh -L 3305:127.0.0.1:3306 192.168.1.14) and then use this connection url

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3305/test
```

It would be easier to assist if we'd known your operating system.

If this is a deployment situation, opening the firewall for port 3306 from your IP address is probably the right thing. In linux you might find the settings in /etc/sysconfig/iptables, but your sysadmin may have other safe guards in place. You must also verify that mysql is actually listening on the IP-address, and not only localhost.

Comment: +1 for the hint that mysql can be configured to listen on localhost only, so that no "GRANT..." and no firewall configuration will help. Has bitten me once.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is standard protected so you can't access it remotely. You'll have to grant MySQL as well as the user connecting to MySQL access from outside the MySQL-machine.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a low-level network issue.

Can you ping that IP ?
Can you telnet to that IP/port ?

e.g. `telnet 192.168.1.14 3306`

Establishing whether you can talk to the machine and whether you can create a basic TCP connection to the MySQL process on that machine will tell you a lot - is your network sound, is a process listening on that port etc.

Comment: Hello Brain Agnew,
I tried as what you told. But it shows following

C:\Documents and Settings\Net Cafe>telnet 192.168.1.14 3306
Connecting To 192.168.1.14...Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306
: Connect failed

Comment: So either you don't have a route (did ping work) or MySql is not listening on that port (perhaps listening on another port, or not listening at all)