# How to connect to a remote MySQL database with Java?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

I am trying to create a JSF application using the Eclipse IDE. I am using a remote mySQL server as my database. How do I connect to this remote database for creating tables and accessing them?

Answer (score 45):

Just supply the IP / hostname of the remote machine in your database connection string, instead of `localhost`. For example:

```
jdbc:mysql://192.168.15.25:3306/yourdatabase
```

Make sure there is no firewall blocking the access to port `3306`

Also, make sure the user you are connecting with is allowed to connect from this particular hostname. For development environments it is safe to do this by `'username'@'%'`. Check [the user creation manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html) and the [`GRANT` manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html).

Comment: Also, be sure to GRANT appropriate permissions to that host and user in your MySQL schema.

Comment: @Angeline: Pls accept this answer, since this is the correct answer for the question asked

Comment: Also make sure that: (1) Your PC's IP address is among those IPs allowed to connect remotely to your database server. (2) Your database's name - as given in the URL - will be the full qualified name for that database. So if the actual database is called 'web_shop' and it's held on a hosting account called say 'angelazza' then your database's fully qualified name is 'angelazza_web_shop' .

Comment: And (3) Change all references within an .sql file uploaded to the database server (assuming that you develop the DB offline and upload/paste it to the server) from 'web_shop' to 'angelazza_web_shop' to avoid error.

Answer (score 9):

You need to pass IP/hostname of the rempote machine in the connection string.

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.sql.*;

public class Connect
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
       Connection conn = null;

       try
       {

           String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
           Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url,"root"," ");
           System.out.println ("Database connection established");
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();

       }
       finally
       {
           if (conn != null)
           {
               try
               {
                   conn.close ();
                   System.out.println ("Database connection terminated");
               }
               catch (Exception e) { /* ignore close errors */ }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Instead of local host i replaced my remote machine address. this is the code: `String url = "jdbc:mysql://172.18.227.237/struts2"; conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","admin")`;. But Now I get the error, `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'root'@'172.20.169.174' to database 'struts2'. I have obtained remote access to the mysql server.

Comment: A little late to the party with this, but: replace "jdbc:mysql://172.18.227.237/struts2" with "jdbc:mysql://172.18.227.237:3306/struts2" (note the port number). In case some behind me makes this same mistake.

Comment: You will never, ever, for any purpose or reason, be able to connect to a remote machine using either localhost or 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 4):

to access database from remote machine , you need to give grant all privileges to you data base.

run the following script to give permissions:
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO user@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

Answer (score 2):

Plus, you should make sure the MySQL server's config (/etc/mysql/my.cnf, /etc/default/mysql on Debian) doesn't have "skip-networking" activated and is not binded exclusively to the loopback interface (127.0.0.1) but also to the interface/IP address you want connect to.

Comment: Remember to restart mysql on the remote machine by `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart` after this change.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new user in the schema ‘mysql’ (mysql.user)
   Run this code in your mysql work space 

   `“GRANT ALL ON . to user@'%'IDENTIFIED BY '';`
2. Open the ‘3306’ port at the machine which is having the Data Base.

     `Control Panel -> 
     Windows Firewall -> 
     Advance Settings -> 
     Inbound Rules -> 
     New Rule -> 
     Port ->
     Next -> 
     TCP & set port as 3306 ->
     Next -> 
     Next ->
     Next ->
     Fill Name and Description ->
     Finish ->`
3. Try to check by a telnet msg on cmd including DB server's IP

Comment: And port forwarding when you are behind NAT!

Comment: I understood better with the 2nd Answer there: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700518/remote-mysql-database-access

Answer (score 1):

Close all the connection which is open & connected to the server listen port, whatever it is from application or client side tool (navicat) or on running server (apache or weblogic). First close all connection then restart all tools MySQL,apache etc.

Answer (score 1):

Change the IP / hostname of the vps in your database connection string, instead of localhost. For example if my IP is 193.23.127.130:

```
jdbc:mysql://193.23.127.130:3306/yourdatabase
```

then make sure your vps firewall allow port 3306 for MySQL.

Then go to MySQL workbench, Server–Users and Privileges, create an account (in this case account: remoteUser, password:password), make sure Limit to Hosts Matching is % (means you can access from any other IP)
[image: create user]

Then set password and grant rights then apply
[image: grant rights]

then you can add the following code in Java to access remotely

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://193.23.127.130:3306/swing_demo", "remoteUser", "password");
```

Answer (score 0):

in my.cnf file , please change the following

## Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
 ## localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
 ## bind-address          = 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, after creating localhost and '%' versions of the user, and granting appropriate access to database.tables for both, I had to comment out the 'bind-address' in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysql.cnf and restart mysql as sudo.

## bind-address           = 127.0.0.1