# MySQL connectivity from an external network with java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Hey guys i'm trying to connect mysql database from my friend's wifi. The database connects and works fine from all my other devices with are all on the same network but i want to connect to the database from an external network(my friends network).

I have replaced localhost/device ip with my public ip address which i got from whatsmyip.com

String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://myPublicIp:3306/trial";

and i ran it from my friend's home:

this is what i got:

com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception:

**BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION**
java.net.Connect.Exception
MESSAGE: Connection timed out: connect

As i said there is no prob with the code, it works fine for locally connected devices. I wanted to know if my string's syntax is wrong.
Assuming my public ip address is 50.50.50.50 and my device running mysql is 192.168.x.x and the port is 3306 how should i format my string.
Thanks.

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318250/how-to-connent-to-a-remote-mysql-database-with-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should forward your 3306 port for the device which got the database on it, otherwise your router can't decide which device to look for when you request connection through this port and it won't let anything through instead.

Comment: I just port forwarded 3306 and it still shows the same error. I checked if port is open and its a yes.

Comment: TCP? Your connection url is fine, it worked inside your network, your problem is that you cannot connect to your IP through this port.

Comment: thank u its working :D had issues with port forwarding now its fixed.