# How to connect to SQLite Database that's on my PC from Android phone using Wi-fi?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, wifi

I have to make an app for Android that can connect to a local SQLite Database that is on a computer (the Android phone and the computer are connected on the same router with wi-fi) and just use the data from the database in my Android app. Is there any way to do that without making a server? Can I access the database if I know the IP address of the computer and the directory where the database is stored on the computer and if I can, how??

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do this without making a server. The server would be required to allow the device to communicate with the database.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make server on your own computer (of course u can), but you can use https://www.elephantsql.com/ .

You can access to the database using jdbc http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-create-database.htm.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I don't want to use remote servers, the goal was not to use servers at all but according to the replies I have to :)

Comment: Do you read this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318250/how-to-connent-to-a-remote-mysql-database-with-java] , I think thats all  you need.

Comment: Yes, this is with using MySQL Server, I was asking if I can make it without any servers or a server based database but it looks like it's not possible, so I'll do it with sql server