# Use Java to remotely backup a MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql

I trying to create software which will backup MySQL databases remotely via Java. I do not have access to any console, but I am able to run MySQL commands and statements. I need to backup the databases into ".sql" files which can then be used to restore.

How can I go about backing up MySQL without the console? Is it possible to do a sqldump?

My current thought is to do the following procedure for each table:

1. Use SHOW TABLES to list the tables to backup
2. Get table names
3. Get table schema with `SHOW COLUMNS FROM tablename;`
4. Count total rows
5. Select all from table in increments of 1000 rows (to keep track of
   percentage downloaded)
6. While doing this, have a FileOutputStream open to write data as it
   is received into a file. It will also place the drop if exists,
   create with the schema, lock, and insert into as seen in a '.sql'
   file.

Is there a better way to do this, or is my method the best for my situation? Will my method work?

Comment: The "better way to do this" is over SSH or a server-side cron job.

Comment: Yeah, but I have no access to that. This is for Backuo software I sell which people use on VPS and other kinds of shared servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use JDBC to fire plain SQL commands at the database just like you would when using the mysql command line interface. That way you have full control of each step of the dump, e.g. show the progress when fetching 1000s increments, write a concurrent log or report etc.

Comment: So basically my proposed method will work and it will allow me to show progress? Because I need to show progress.

Comment: Yes, of course. You can do a count query of how many data you can expect beforehand, and the start to fetch the data page-wise. It's a lot more work than just calling  ``mysqldump`` via JVM runtime, however, you're in control of everything.

Comment: I am working on this now, and the only things I am having problems with is the schema and blobs. Is there an easier way to get a schema than `SHOW COLUMNS FROM tablename;`?

Comment: I found a magical SQL command to do just what I need: `SHOW CREATE TABLE table;` gives the exact string you see in a `.sql` file used to create the table. Its perfect.

Answer (score -1):

Your thought is reason able, but a lot of things to implement (Get table structure with JDBC Meta data, define your own backup format, etc).

Since you can connect to remote MySQL with JDBC, you have the Hostname/port/username/password for the server. Can you run 

`String cmd = "mysqldump -h host -P port -u user -p password –database dbname > backup.sql";
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec(cmd);`

Make sure mysqldump is on your PATH.

Comment: Wouldn't that execute the command on that computer? I need to do this remotely from a different server. Also, how would I show progress with this?

Answer (score -1):

You can run following in JAVA or Shell Script

`$ mysqldump -u [uname] -p[pass] db_name > <FILE_PATH>db_backup.sql`

This will dump your DB to a file.

Comment: Wouldn't this only work if the MySQL server is on the same machine? I need to do it remotely with a way to track the progress.

Comment: You can remotely connect to MySQL for Java https://stackoverflow.com/a/2320117/2334568

Comment: Yes I get that part, but how do I execute that command to save the file. I am on machine1 and I need to execute that command on machine2 remotely then get the file from machine2 to machine1 while tracking progress.