# How to use multiple database on different host using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this array that store the connection info and i want to use it when perform the query

```
$dblist = array();

$dblist[] = array(
        'host'=>'192.168.1.20',
        'username'=>'root',
        'password'=>'root1',
        'database'=>'unsubscribe_1',
        'table'=>'subscribers'
        );

$dblist[] = array(
        'host'=>'192.168.1.5',
        'username'=>'root',
        'password'=>'root2',
        'database'=>'unsubscribe_test',
        'table'=>'subscribers2'
        );


foreach($dblist as $list)
{
$host = $list['host'];
$username = $list['username'];
$password = $list['password'];
$db = $list['database'];
$tb = $list['table'];

$conn1 = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db,$conn1) or die(mysql_error());

$sql = "select * from $db";
$query = mysql_query($sql,$conn1) or die(mysql_error());    
}
```

The problem is i keep getting this error "Host '192.168.1.5' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"

What is the problem here?

Comment: Host '192.168.1.5' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Comment: I am pretty sure it is allowed because i am working in that 192.168.1.5 (localhost)

Comment: What happens if you swap the order of the array so 192.168.1.5 is connected first?

Comment: **You cannot be sure!** Just because you're watching this error message with your own eyes! So, the only thing you can be sure of - it's that your host isn't allowed! The only thing you really need is to trust your eyes, not fantasies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume Host '192.168.1.5' is your local machine and you encounter this error when trying to connect to Host .20, You need to enable remote access for Host .5 on Host .20's MySQl server.

[HowTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700518/remote-mysql-database-access/1700570#1700570)

-michael