# Connect to mysql remote database using JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection

I'm a java beginner and I'm working on a simple application which connects to a remote mysql database using JDBC. I've tested it locally and it works just fine, however I cannot get it to work on for my remote server.
I don't think its of much use but heres the code:

```
Connection connection = null;
String dburl = "jdbc:mysql://314159265:3306/Db_Name";
String userName = "user";
String passWord = "password";

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, userName, passWord);
        Statement st = connection.createStatement();                                 

        String query = "INSERT INTO Example (`TestColumn`) VALUES('hello')";
        int rsI = st.executeUpdate(query);
        System.out.println("Hi");
        }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
                System.out.println("Database connection terminated");
            } catch (Exception e) { /* ignore close errors */ }
        }
    }
```

When I run this, I get the following message:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

I'm pretty sure it must be some kind of server configuration issue.

```
 Notes:
 Username, password, IP, database name, etc. are just examples.
```

Comment: Just a guess here, but is your host really 314159265? Should that be some sort of IP or is that really a DNS name?

Comment: Do you have to set up some kind of ssh/ssl tunnel to the remote server before accessing the driver? Also - can you access the database using a remote query browser on a client system? From memory I think you have to configure it so that the database is exposed, by default I am pretty sure databases are only available on local host so when you connect to the JDBC you will be getting rejected. I bet your java code works on the same server as the database

Comment: Can you reach that machine `31415...` from your machine (where you're running that program from)? Try to ping that "address" or telnet into it on port 3306

Comment: did u try st.execute(querry); instead of int rsI = st.executeUpdate(query);

Comment: Have you configured the remote database to accept remote connections from this user and host?

Comment: @btiernay its not the actual IP

Comment: You have that because the connection to that IP has timed out. Verify the connection is still open and accepting requests

Comment: one more question. is this complete stack trace. Could you post compete stack trace

Comment: @FaddishWorm no ssh/ssl tunnel. How can I configure the database to be exposed?

Comment: @Bhanu Kaushik I had no clue what a stack trace is 30 secs ago but from what I've just read yes this is the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. This could be a firewall problem, or a configuration problem. But I don't think it is a coding problem at all - you need to start troubleshooting the connection.
2. Trouble shoot by attempting to use third party client apps to connect to mysql. This will indicate whether it is configured for external access. Although it doesn't ensure that JDBC is visible from the outside, it does rule out some potential firewall problems.
3. Follow this guide to help you mess with your configurations

[Remote MYSQL Database Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700518/remote-mysql-database-access)

If you are still stuck, it could be a coding problem so check out this page:

[How to connent to a remote mysql database with java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318250/how-to-connent-to-a-remote-mysql-database-with-java)

P.S. I am assuming you are using unix as the operating system.

Comment: It turns out the host provider is blocking remote connections to the database

Comment: sweet - glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score -3):

I guess 314159265 could be replaced by some address....
like jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
or jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/